# What is the relation between position vector, relative velocity and time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, vectors

Two particles having position vector r1=(3i+4j)m and r2=(-5i-3j)m are moving with velocity v1=(4i+3j)m/s and v2=(ai+7j)m/s collide after 2 seconds then the value of a is   (i solved it graphically but it took more than given time, so how can i solve it using relations of physics)

Comment: Hi Manish and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If velocity is constant, then the change in position is velocity times time.
$$r' = r + vt$$
where $r'$ is the new position.

If two objects collide, then they must be at the same position at the same time.
$$r_1' = r_2'$$